# How to order similar compound lifts in the same workout?

Tags: workout-routines

For a while I found myself performing similar compound lifts in the same workout session, e.g., flat bench press and inclined bench press, front squat and back squat, etc.
Im uncertain whether I should do such lifts back to back or place them at the start and end of workout maximizing the time in between.

While I know that it's generally recomended to perform compound lifts at the start when you have most energy, I struggle to achive adequate performance with inclined bench press after going to complete failure with flat bench press. So I have to intersperse them with other chest exercises.

With squats on other hand, I really only can do them back to back as at the end of the leg day I'm simply very exhausted. Since front squats are harder for me, I put them first. But even so, I know that if I try to increase the weight I will certainly compromise my back squats performance.

So this begs the question, is there a silver bullet solution? Or it's nothing but trial and error, seeing what works best?

Comment: There is a silver bullet, which is *train those movements on different days*, and if you’re open to that as a solution, I’ll write up an outline of how I’ve organized my training to avoid exactly the problem you’re describing.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, unfortunately due to other physical activities I only can place my workouts in three consequetive days a week. And in particular, I was given a program by a trainer which had dedicated "days" for chest & biceps, shoulders & triceps, legs, back & core. I dont see any way I can split those.

Comment: Perhaps Ill close this question and open anew one where I would outline my program and maybe someone can reccomend a better reaarangment within those 3 days.

Comment: My training is three days a week. Not consecutive, but it could be done that way and work just fine.

Comment: "I don't see any way I can split those." What's stopping you from doing three days, each day consisting of 1/3 of your chest & biceps workout, 1/3 of your shoulders & triceps workout, and 1/3 of your legs, back and core workout?